# Calculating eigen-values and -vectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If the vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$ are in the columns of $X$, then what are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of
$$B = XAX^{-1},$$
where $$A= \begin{bmatrix}2&3\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Is there any way to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors easier than multiplying the whole matrix and then solving $\det(B-\lambda I) = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrices $A$ and $XAX^{-1}$ are similar and therefore they have the same eigenvalues:  $1$ and $2$.

On the other hand, if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $Xv$ is an eigenvector of $XAX^{-1}$. So, compute the two eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ of $A$, and then compute $Xv_1$ and $Xv_2$.

Comment: can you please explain to me how $A$ and $XAX^{-1}$ are similar?

P.S.:- sorry, if it's a too basic question.

Comment: What do you think “similar” means?

Comment: similar as in their eigenvalues are same

Comment: [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity)!

Comment: ohh! thanks for the info!